# Downshift.js as a list filter

Tags: reactjs, filter, downshift

I just wanted to try and see how Downshift could be used as a list filter, ie the "drop down" menu doesn't close.

I found that fairly easy, but then found it pretty difficult to overcome the default behaviour that when you click an item, [the input is populated with its value](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/kentcdodds/downshift-examples?file=/src/downshift/ordered-examples/01-basic-autocomplete.js).

I've create an example of how I would tackle this (see below), but it seems complicated. Ideally I would've liked to just do a prevent default type thing on the click handler and provided my own, but I didn't see an obvious way of doing that. What is the Downshift recommended way?

https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-leavitt-pyruxj?file=/src/downshift/ordered-examples/02-complete-autocomplete.js (click the module preview button)

I started by overriding the click behaviour, but then found I also needed to do blur and others, and i didn't want to miss an edge case.

Answer (score -1):

You should use the `itemToString` prop and return an empty string.

```
<Downshift
  ...
  itemToString={() => ""}
>
```